# How to download a .swf file from a page's html code?

Tags: html, download, flash

There is one html page that contains only a .swf file that can be streaming from there:

http://tvoy-start.ru/uroki/1nedel/1nedel.html

Here is that page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- saved from url=(0025)http://www.techsmith.com/ -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="DC.date" content="2011-09-15 11:37:43 " />
        <meta name="DC.language" content="ENU" />
        <meta name="DC.title" content="1nedel" />

        <title>РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРѕ Camtasia Studio 6</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.registerObject("csSWF", "9.0.115", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body 
            {
                background-color: #1a1a1a;
                font: .8em/1.3em verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #media
            {
                margin-top: 40px;
            }
            #noUpdate
            {
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: x-small;
                color: #cccccc;
                text-align: left;
                width: 210px; 
                height: 200px;  
                padding: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="media">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="900" height="420" id="csSWF">

                <param name="movie" value="1nedel_controller.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=false&thumb=FirstFrame.png&thumbscale=45&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="1nedel_controller.swf" width="900" height="420">

                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
                    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                    <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=false&thumb=FirstFrame.png&thumbscale=45&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <div id="noUpdate">
                        <p>The Camtasia Studio video content presented here requires a more recent version of the Adobe Flash Player. If you are you using a browser with JavaScript disabled please enable it now. Otherwise, please update your version of the free Flash Player by <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">downloading here</a>.</p>

                    </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
        <!-- Users looking for simple object / embed tags can copy and paste the needed tags below.
        <div id="media">
            <object id="csSWF" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="900" height="420" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0">
                <param name="src" value="1nedel_controller.swf"/>
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a"/>
                <param name="quality" value="best"/>
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
                <param name="scale" value="showall"/>
                <param name="flashVars" value="autostart=false"/>
                <embed name="csSWF" src="1nedel_controller.swf" width="900" height="420" bgcolor="#1a1a1a" quality="best" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" scale="showall" flashVars="autostart=false&thumb=FirstFrame.png&thumbscale=45&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
            </object>
        </div>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I wonder, where in the page's source, if it’s possible at all, can I find the link so that I could download that .swf file onto my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's specified as "movie" param under object tag.
You can reach it at http://tvoy-start.ru/uroki/1nedel/1nedel_controller.swf

However, the swf file may have some server side control that doesn't allow you to see streaming if you aren't on that website. Just try.

**EDIT:** Forgot, you have to save the page, in my browser (firefox) is File->Save page with name
On internet explorer is the engine wheel icon->File->Save as

On other browsers, I don't know at the moment

Comment: Thanks. I reached it there and I can even watch it there. But I still have no idea how I could download it from there?

Comment: You have to do File "Save page with name" in your browser (I'm using firefox)

Comment: Do you mean "Save File as..." (shortcut is cntrl+S)? If yes, then I can only download some 398 kbt, which is obviously not the whole file.

Comment: Yes I mean that, and it **is** the whole file (a streaming swf file is very small, only code), as I've said it could be all server-driven. In this case, **everything** is server driven, you can't download what you are watching without third party programs (you can try orbit downloader) or simply you can't if server code is well done, can block any connection that do not come from their swf file.